# What conceptual error am I making in limit evaluation?

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin[\cos x]}{1+\cos x}$  where $[.]$  denotes the floor function.

Attempt:

As $x\to 0$, $\cos x \to  1$ and therefore $[\cos x]\to 1$ $\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin[\cos x]}{1+\cos x} = \dfrac{\sin 1}{2}$

However, the answer is $0$. What is the concept mistake in my solution?

Comment: The floor function is not continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $x\ne0$ but $|x|<\pi/2$, then $0<\cos x<1$ so that
$[\cos x]=0$ and $\sin[\cos x]=0$. Therefore $\lim_{x\to0}\sin[\cos x]=0$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(\lim_{x\to a} x)=f(a)$ only if $f$ is continuous.  That's pretty much the entire point of limits;  that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ne f(a)$.

for $x \in [0, 2\pi)$, $[\cos x] = 1$ if AND ONLY IF $x = 0$. When $x \to 0$, $x$ itself does NOT equal zero, and when $x \to 0$, $[\cos x] = 0$ and $x\to 0\not\implies [\cos x]\to [\cos 0]=1$.  In fact.  $x\to 0\implies [\cos x]=0\to 0$ instead.

This is the **exact** same reason if $f(x) = x; x < 2$ and $f(x)=5 + x^2; x \ge 2$ then $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x) \ne f(\lim_{x\to 2^-} x) = f(2) = 9$.

Comment: Congrats on 50k reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} \lim_{x\to{0}^{+}} cosx = {1}^{-} \end{align}
So \begin{align} \lfloor{ cosx }\rfloor = \lfloor{ {1}^{-} }\rfloor = 0 \end{align}
And \begin{align} \lim_{x\to{0}^{-}} cosx = {1}^{-} \end{align}
So \begin{align} \lfloor{ cosx }\rfloor = \lfloor{ {1}^{-}}\rfloor = 0 \end{align}
Now you know where you were wrong